Trying to pass a structure from C++ to Kotlin through JNI, and I am having to do endian conversion and bit shifting, is there a better way to do this?
I have a union defined in C++, as follows:
static union uns {
    uint64_t                     data;

    struct {
        uint64_t                     a : 32;
        uint64_t                     b : 5;
        uint64_t                     c : 6;
        uint64_t                     d : 21;
    } m;
};

This union I am then passing over to Kotlin as an unsigned int 64 (I require it to be an unsigned int 64 and cannot be any other data type), like below:
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity_passStruct(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

    uns *u = new uns;

    u->m.a = 35000000;
    u->m.b = 12;
    u->m.c = 2;
    u->m.d = 100035;


    jobject byteBuffer = env->NewDirectByteBuffer(u, sizeof(*u));

    return byteBuffer;
}

Now, to get the data in the union I am having to do endian conversions and also shift bits in accordance with the structure, this is what I am doing over in Kotlin:
val byteBufferStruct = passStruct()
        byteBufferStruct.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)

        val passedValue = byteBufferStruct.long
        val a = passedValue and 0xFFFFFFFF
        val b = (passedValue shr 32) and 0x1F
        val c = (passedValue shr 37) and 0x3F
        val d = (passedValue shr 43) and 0x1FFFFF


        val logMessage = "Extracted struct data: $a, $b, $c, $d."
        Log.w("FF: ", logMessage)

And now to send it back, I am sending the same bytebuffer back and reading it in C++ again through the below JNI function:
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity_receiveByteBufferStruct(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject byteBuffer) {
    uint8_t *data = static_cast<uint8_t*>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(byteBuffer));

    uint64_t packedValue = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(data);

    uns nu;
    nu.data = packedValue;
    
    uint64_t a = nu.m.a;
    uint64_t b = nu.m.b;
    uint64_t c = nu.m.c;
    uint64_t d = nu.m.d;

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FF: JNI", "Received struct byte buffer: %d, %d, %d, %d", a, static_cast<int>(b), static_cast<int>(c), d);
}

Now, this works and I am able to read data in both Kotlin and C++ through this method however, I am trying to find a better solution. That does not require endian conversions and bit shifting. As the data I am passing can change in the future. Also, not limiting myself to ByteBuffer open to any other way through which I can pass and accurately read the above mentioned Union in Kotlin and back to C++. I require it to be an unsigned int 64 and it cannot be any other data type. Looking for a solution that is native and not using any third party plugins or libraries
I am trying to avoid the use of the endian conversion and bit shifting, as that will limit the use cases of our Union, where if in the future the struct has more or less members, then it will be a pain to reimplement the same. Which is why I am looking for a way to pass the same structure without having to do what I am doing in Kotlin right now.

OT: In the Java_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity_passStruct function there's no need for u to be a pointer. Remember, in C++ you can create objects without using new. In fact, you using new there leads to a memory leak as you don't free the object you create.

Another problem is in the Java_com_example_jnitest_MainActivity_receiveByteBufferStruct function, where you use the union for type-punning. While it will likely work it's officially undefined behavior. In C++ the last written member of a union is the only you can read from.

Hey @Someprogrammerdude, yes, thanks for those pointers. This is just a sample POC that I was trying to get working. These issues won't exist/will be ironed out as we never use new in our codebase like that.

You have a solution that is native and does not use any libraries. It's just brittle and awkward to use. If you absolutely must keep this format, I would use Kaitai struct bit integers to describe your data and have it generate a parser/serializer for your Java code to use. That would also formalize the actual layout of your bitstring since C++, well, doesn't.

Hey @Botje, yes indeed. It is a solution however it is not a good solution. This will limit us in many ways, for example, if union was to change and incorporate more or less members then it would be a pain to create bespoke implementations with each iteration. We are trying to avoid that because we are currently building a system for multiple OSes and want to generalize the approach as much as possible. I know that FFM provides more efficient mapping to C++'s unsigned data types but it is still experimental and we are trying to avoid anything unstable. Hence the need for a better way.

I was pointing out the hypocrisy of "not using any third party plugins of libraries". You could, for example, take Apache Common's BitField class, make it work with Java longs (or arbitrary memory, really) and compose a few instances in a higher-level object. That reduces your per-iteration work to modifying the bitmasks and changing the API of the higher-level object.
